# WSO2IS - Access failure for API: /openapi/v1, version: v1 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I tried to configure but I can't login.

[It said 'OAuth2 realm="WSO2 API Manager", error="invalid token", error_description="The access token expired"' & Authorization: Bearer null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWS5p.jpg)

[Resident Identity Provider Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6VWP.jpg)

[WSO2 carbon log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqTcs.jpg)

[WSO2 API configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ3ak.jpg)

[This is my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOfxU.jpg)

Now, I can get the [response 200 with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdXZn.jpg), then stuck at the API GW with the response:

```html
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900901</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Access failure for API: /openapi/v1, version: v1 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have given the correct access token</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

How should I do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please share more details on what are you trying to achieve and what problems you are facing and if possible a screen capture of the error, etc. Thanks!

Comment: I already share the 5 images above; do you have any more information request me to share?

Comment: Can you let us know what you are trying to achieve high-level? Whats is the use case?

Comment: I'm trying to generate JWT token for website authentication.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshots, you are getting a 200 response for the token request. But the API call does not include an access token (it is null).

Therefore, you have to check why the value "null" being added there. It could be an issue with your application where it is unable to parse the token response and add it back to API call, or you do not get an access token even though the token response returns a 200.

Comment: I deleted all WSO2AM, WSO2IS, and their DBs. Then reinstall all of them again, it work fine. I think it's cause from I installed the older version before then changed to this version without deleted the DBs first.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Today, I found the issue again, I already tried to reinstalled 2 times, it's not solve. Do you have any suggestions?